# if this divisors such $d_{1}+d_{2}+\cdots+d_{k-1}=n-1$,then there exsit $m$ such $n=2^m$

Tags: number-theory

**Interesting  Question:**

> let $n\ge 2$ be a positive integer,with divisors
>   $$1=d_{1}<d_{2}<\cdots<d_{k-1}<d_{k}=n$$
>   and such
>   $$d_{1}+d_{2}+\cdots+d_{k-1}=n-1$$
>
> show that:there exsit postive integer $m$ such $$n=2^m$$

My idea: such $n=4$,then $d_{1}=1,d_{2}=2,d_{3}=4$
so
$$d_{1}+d_{2}=3=n-1$$

(2):$n=8$, then $d_{1}=1,d_{2}=2,d_{3}=4,d_{4}=8$,so
$$d_{1}+d_{2}+d_{3}=7=8-1=n-1$$
and so on,

But I can't prove this nice reslut.can you help me?

Hello,André Nicolas,Thank you ,I think your remark is my inverse problem,and not my problem proof,do you agree with me?

Comment: The answer is to your problem as stated. The converse problem is straightforward, I added a remark about it. It is undoubtedly easy for you, but I added it because though your question asks whether there are any non-powers of $2$ with your property (open problem) your calculations dealt with the converse.

Answer (score 5):

These are the [Almost Perfect Numbers.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_perfect_number) The only *known* almost perfect numbers are the powers of $2$, but it has not been *proved* that they are the only ones.

**Remark:** What you were writing out is the start of a proof of the **converse** result. If $n=2^m$, then indeed the sum of the divisors of $2^m$ other than $2^m$ is equal to $n-1$. For this sum is the finite geometric series $1+2+\cdots+2^{m-1}$, which has sum $2^m-1$.